# UWP - need sample how to consume OData service

Tags: uwp, odata

Can anybody please explain how to get data from a table and related table with OData ConnectedService, in UWP application?
I have this code in my ViewModel:

```
public async Task<bool> LoadData()
{
    bool returnValue = false;

    this.OrderTypeCollection = new ObservableCollection<OrderType>();
    this.OrderSelectedItem = new Order();

    try
    {
        // Use same data context
        OrderApplicationEntities context = new OrderApplicationEntities(AppStorage.Instance.OrderApplicationDataServiceUri);

        // Get Orders with expanded OrderTypes
        var queryOrder = from v in context.Orders.Expand("OrderType") select v;
        DataServiceQuery<Order> dataServiceQueryOrder = (DataServiceQuery<Order>)queryOrder;
        TaskFactory<IEnumerable<Order>> taskFactoryOrder = new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<Order>>();
        IEnumerable<Order> resultOrder = await taskFactoryOrder.FromAsync(dataServiceQueryOrder.BeginExecute(null, null), iar => dataServiceQueryOrder.EndExecute(iar));

        // Set selected Order
        this.OrderSelectedItem = resultOrder.ElementAt(0);

        // Get OrderTypes
        var queryOrderType = from v in context.OrderTypes select v;
        DataServiceQuery<OrderType> dataServiceQueryOrderType = (DataServiceQuery<OrderType>)queryOrderType;
        TaskFactory<IEnumerable<OrderType>> taskFactoryOrderType = new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<OrderType>>();
        IEnumerable<OrderType> resultOrderType = await taskFactoryOrderType.FromAsync(dataServiceQueryOrderType.BeginExecute(null, null), iar => dataServiceQueryOrderType.EndExecute(iar));
        ObservableCollection<OrderType> OrderTypeCollection = new ObservableCollection<OrderType>();

        // Set collection of available OrderTypes
        foreach (var v in resultOrderType)
        {
            OrderTypeCollection.Add(v);
        }

        this.OrderTypeCollection = OrderTypeCollection;

        returnValue = true;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

It works and loads Orders with expanded OrderTypes entities, but first - from what I remember from Silverlight - it looks ... over encumbered.
Second, when I use it in XAML combobox like this:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Margin="{StaticResource MediumLeftTopRightBottomMargin}"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.OrderTypeCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.OrderSelectedItem.OrderType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="ComboBoxItem">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

then it doesnt show current OrderType. Dropdown shows available OrderTypes correctly, but when I select some OrderType - I get 'stack overflow' exception. How do I use it right?

Answer (score 0):

Figured - old Silverlight code works fine indeed. And there's much more help about 
 "WCF data service" for Silverlight, than for UWP. This code works fine:

```
NorthwindEntities northwindEntity = new NorthwindEntities( new Uri( "http://localhost:54248/Services/SampleAdoNetDataService.svc/" ) );

public static void BeginLoadingProducts( Categories category )
{
    DataServiceQuery<Products> categoryProducts = northwindEntity
        .CreateQuery<Products>( string.Format( "Categories({0})/Products", category.CategoryID ) )
        .Expand( "Suppliers" )
        .Expand( "Categories" );
    categoryProducts.BeginExecute(
        ( IAsyncResult result ) => EntitiesLoaded<Products>( result, category.Products ),
        categoryProducts );
}
private static void EntitiesLoaded<T>( IAsyncResult result, Collection<T> entities )
{
    DataServiceQuery<T> query = result.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<T>;
    foreach ( T entity in query.EndExecute( result ) )
    {
        entities.Add( entity );
    }
}
```